# Ansible error: "The Python 2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module"

Tags: python, pip, ansible

Im trying to pip install a requirements file in my python3 environment using the following task

```
pip:
  python3: yes
  requirements: ./requirements/my_requirements.txt
  extra_args: -i http://mypypi/windows/simple
```

I checked which version ansible is running  on the controller node (RH7) and it's 3.6.8

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.9
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/{hidden}/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Jun 11 2019, 15:15:01) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
No config file found; using defaults
```

I am however getting the following error:

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The Python 2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. If you require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module
instead.. The Python 2 yum module is needed for this module. If you require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module instead."}
```

My controller node is running RH7.
The targets are centos7 (provisioned by vagrantfiles)

Does anyonek now how to solve this?

Comment: This is not your controller giving you an issue but your node, I would say. Install python 3 on the node would be a solution.

Comment: well, that's what im trying to do with ansible...and that is the first thing done in my ansible script, install python3.  that succeeds.  but when it now comes time to pip install additional libraries..i get the above error

Comment: Did you try using the `dnf` module as suggested by the error message? If so, what was the result?

Comment: no..as i wasn't sure if that fail if i were to try and install on a diff flavor of the OS.  what i did instead is use the virtual_command property instead to explicitly invoke python3. (i think some of these modules need work unfortunately...seems im having to fall back on the command module quite a bit also)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the "Amazon Linux 2" distribution that uses yum, but does not support dnf as of this writing.

As mentioned in the comments above, my problem was in the ansible-managed nodes (AWS EC2 instances running Amazon Linux 2) and not in the controller.

Solved it by imposing the use of python2,  adding `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2` for this group of hosts in the ansible inventory file, as in the following snippet:

```
[amz_linux]
server2 ansible_host=ec2-xx-yy-zz-pp.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com


[amz_linux:vars]
ansible_user=ec2-user
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2
```

Tried it with this playbook, adapted from a [Redhat quick guide](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/system-administrators-guide-getting-started-ansible-fast).

```
---
- hosts: amz_linux
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - name: install Apache server
     yum:
       name: httpd
       state: latest

   - name: enable and start Apache server
     service:
       name: httpd
       enabled: yes
       state: started

   - name: create web admin group
     group:
       name: web
       state: present

   - name: create web admin user
     user:
       name: webadm
       comment: "Web Admin"
       groups: web
       append: yes

   - name: set content directory group/permissions 
     file:
       path: /var/www/html
       owner: root
       group: web
       state: directory
       mode: u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx,g+s

   - name: create default page content
     copy:
       content: "Welcome to {{ ansible_fqdn}} on {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
       dest: /var/www/html/index.html
       owner: webadm
       group: web
       mode: u=rw,g=rw,o=r
```

Actual ansible-playbook run (after using ssh-add to add the instance private key to the ssh agent.)

```
$ ansible-playbook -i ansible/hosts ansible/apache_amz_linux.yaml 

PLAY [amz_linux] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************
The authenticity of host 'ec2-xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (xxxxxxxxxxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:klksjdflskdjflskdfjsldkfjslkdjflskdjf/sdkfj.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
ok: [server2]

TASK [install Apache server] **********************************************************************************************
changed: [server2]

TASK [enable and start Apache server] *************************************************************************************
changed: [server2]

TASK [create web admin group] *********************************************************************************************
changed: [server2]

TASK [create web admin user] **********************************************************************************************
changed: [server2]

TASK [set content directory group/permissions] ****************************************************************************
changed: [server2]

TASK [create default page content] ****************************************************************************************
changed: [server2]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
server2                    : ok=7    changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify

```
ansible-playbook
```

to

```
ansible-playbook -e ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python2
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message can show if your `ansible.cfg` file's `inventory` entry is set to a non-existing file.