# Ansible and Amazon Linux 2: How can I use yum module with Python3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-linux-2

I use Ansible 2.9 to create EC2 instances with Amazon Linux 2. For some purposes I need Python3 on EC2.

So I use option `ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3"`

But with this option module **yum** return error `` pkg_mgr: yum msg: The Python 2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. If you require Python 3 support use the `dnf` Ansible module instead. ``

But Amazon Lunux 2 doesn't work with **dnf**.

The same issue is described here [Ansible error: "The Python 2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100869/ansible-error-the-python-2-bindings-for-rpm-are-needed-for-this-module), and in other forums. Everywhere suggested solution is Python2.

Is there any way to use Python3 and yum? Or the only way is to use **shell** module instead?

Comment: yum hasn't been ported to python 3. You must use python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According information gathered from [other site](https://tekunabe.hatenablog.jp/entry/2019/10/04/ansible_python_interpreter),
you can separate yum and non-yum tasks and use python3 only with non yum tasks:

```
- hosts: testsv
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
 
  tasks:
    # here yum running under python2 without errors
    - name: task1 
      yum:
        list: curl  

    # here yum running under python3
    - name: task2 
      yum:
        list: curl
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

Or try to invert condition:

```
- hosts: testsv
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
 
  tasks:
    # Run yum under python2, and all other tasks under python3
    - name: task2 
      yum:
        list: curl
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python2
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution from @rzlvmp basically works, thank you.
But **yum** anyway use default python, because in **/bin/yum** interpreter is  `#!/usr/bin/python`

So, where are two options:

1. Use vars: `ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3` for a special tasks and Python2 as default.
2. Edit **/bin/yum**:
   `#!/usr/bin/python -> #!/usr/bin/python2`